# Alfresco with Kerberos: Error creating bean with name globalAuthenticationFilter

Tags: kerberos, alfresco, mitkerberos

I configured Alfresco 4.2.c to work with MIT Kerberos, following the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/auth-kerberos-intro.html).
Because the documentation is only for Active Directory, I adapted some part to Kerberos by reading the [forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/authentication-ldap-sso/cifs-login-mit#comment-137659).

Upon starting Alfresco, I get this error:

> 04:01:38,725 ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] CIFS server configuration
>   error, Error creating bean with name 'globalAuthenticationFilter'
>   defined in file
>   [/home/alfresco/alfresco-community-4.2.c-installer-linux-x64/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/kerberos/kerberos-filter-context.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Configuration Error:
>           No such file or directory

I haven't modified the `kerberos-filter-context.xml`.
Any idea what could trigger this message?
I can post any configuration file you want.
No [debug info](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/auth-kerberos-debug.html) gets logged.

Comment: What version of Alfresco?

Comment: @Gagravarr: alfresco-community-4.2.c-installer-linux-x64